# How can I keep the size of my subsubsection the same size as the paragraph font size?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, sections-paragraphs

I would like to keep my subsubsection header the same size of the paragraph font, can someone help me?

at the moment the subsubsection font is the equivalent of \small whilst the paragraph font is \normal.

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

and then I just use `\subsubsection`

Comment: Are you possibly loading an additional package that changes the font size of subsubsection-level headers to `\small`? The `report` document class uses `\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries` as the final argument of the macro `\@startsection` for both subsubsections and paragraphs.

Comment: Can you provide a complete and *minimal* example that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think using `\normalfont` or `\textnormal` inside the `\subsubsection` header can serve your purpose.

```
\subsubsection{\textnormal{I am same as the paragraph font}}
 I am the paragraph.
```

or,

```
\subsubsection{\normalfont I am same as the paragraph font}
 I am the paragraph.
```

Comment: If you are using it more than once or twice this can become tedious (and you may forget at some point setting the font). I think it would be much better to redefine the command `\subsubsection` to include this by default. Or use a class (like `scrreprt`) that lets you change it easily.

Answer (score 1):

The `titlesec` package with `explicit` option lets you have simple formatting commands; e.g.:

```
\titleformat*\subsubsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries\boldmath}{0.5em}{\thesubsubsection.}{#1}
```

where:

- the "optional" argument is the shape of the section; `hang` is LaTeX default.
- next argument is general formatting to be applied to both label and title text.
- 3rd argument is the distance between label and title.
- 4th argument is label formatting (here adding a dot at the end of the label.
- last argument is code that precedes the title (#1 if the `explicit` option was chosen).